# How to stop MongoDB from reloading data every time I refresh a page?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, debugging, refresh

Basically I am practicing `NodeJs/MongoDB` by making a simple blog app. I am using the `.find()` method to final all the saved blogs on the `db`, and then running it through a loop to post it on the main page. That method is called every time the page is refreshed, so

**how do I stop it from being called to avoid automatic reposts?**

```
exports.getBlogEntries = function() {

    Entry.find(function(err, entries) {

        if (!err){ 
            for(i = 1; i < entries.length; i++ ) {
                list.push(entries[i]);
            }
        }
    });
    return list;
};
```

Comment: You'll want to look into caching

Comment: I am new to this...any tips on how I would go about doing that?

Comment: I would suggest using LRU cache ([node-lru-cache](https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache) seems to be nice implementation) so you won't have to worry about overflow. Basically the pattern would be: check if blog entries exist in cache and return then if they do; otherwise read them from MongoDB, insert to cache and return to a customer. I hope that will give you some directions.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> I would suggest using LRU cache ([node-lru-cache](https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache) seems to be nice implementation) so you won't have to worry about overflow. Basically the pattern would be: check if blog entries exist in cache and return then if they do; otherwise read them from MongoDB, insert to cache and return to a customer. I hope that will give you some directions.